# Android Plot flickering issue

Tags: android, androidplot

I am trying to create a realtime chart using AndroidPlot. I add values to my series based on a timer. How to resolve this flickering issue. Ps: I  am new to android and androidPlot
My current code is ->

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils;
import com.androidplot.xy.CatmullRomInterpolator;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.PointLabelFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private XYPlot plot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // initialize our XYPlot reference:
        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.plot);
        actualDraw();

    }
    public void actualDraw()
    {
        final List<Number> ySeries=new ArrayList<Number>();

        Timer timer=new Timer();
        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.WHITE, null, null);
         final SimpleXYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(ySeries,SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
        plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                                  {
                                      public void run()
                                      {
                                          plot.clear();
                                          Random random=new Random();
                                          series1.addLast(series1.size(),random.nextInt(100));
                                          plot.addSeries(series1, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.WHITE, null, null));
                                          plot.redraw();
                                      }
                                  },
                0,      // run first occurrence immediatetly
                100);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the entire plot and recreating / adding your series to the plot every time your timer fires.  Instead you should just add the new value to the series and call redraw.  Change your TimerTask.run() to look like this:

```
public void run() {
    plot.clear();
    Random random=new Random();  
    series1.addLast(series1.size(),random.nextInt(100));
}
```

I'd also suggest reusing the same Random instance instead of initializing a new one each time.